# How much hacking do I need for warbots and dome of york artillery?

Tags: neocron

I have 40 in hack already and I am trying to hack warbots and dome of york artillery but im not having much success in it

How much hack skill do I need to be able to hack these without the possibility of failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hacking in Neocron is not something you can level up to a point where it's no longer possible to fail. Failing a hack is very much down to how you choose to connect up each circuit and in what order, and requires practice, but is made easier by having more points in the hacking (HCK) ability under Intelligence. There is a [very good guide](http://forum.neocron.com/showthread.php?124432-New-Player-Guide-Hacking-in-Neocron-2) on the Neocron forums that details the process of hacking.

Hacking [Warbots, Warbot Titans](http://wiki.techhaven.org/Warbot) and DoY bots can be done with 60 skill points in hack - again, if you're struggling you can go with more points in the hacking ability, if you plan on hacking OPs then you will need much more than 60 anyway.

Comment: thanks so should i try and get as much hacking as possible or is there a point where getting more becomes a waste of points?

Comment: Unless you're creating a dedicated hacking character (ie: for Hacknet) then there is a point that putting more points into hacking becomes a waste, it still makes hacking easier, but there is a point where it becomes *too* easy for everything except OPs and hacknet.